# WPF - Group Styles: Can we only bind to the "Name" property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I am trying to create an ItemsControl which is charged with displaying various items sorted by metadata. Each item can have multiple metadata. For example, an item of type "Conversation" could have a "Chapter", "Act" and "Volume" metadata.

Upon searching how grouping worked in WPF, I found out about GroupStyles and the PropertyGroupDescription class.

I created my own class which inherits from PropertyGroupDescription and which returns an object of type "Metadata".

Is there anyway that in my ItemsControl's GroupStyle DataTemplate I can bind to the object returned (i.e.: the "Metadata" object) and then display its properties as I wish ? Or am I forced to bind to "Name" ?

In other words:

```
<ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                  Am I forced to bind to "Name" here ?
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default `DataContext` in `GroupStyle` you can bind to this [CollectionViewGroup Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613524.aspx). But of course you can set any other [`BindingSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#specifying_the_binding_source) if you need.

If you want the first object in your group use:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].YourStringProperty}" />
```

Comment: But Items is the array of the items and not of the GroupDescription object. I.e. the `Metadata` property remains inaccessible?

Answer (score 0):

By default when doing binding to custom object, it will try display using its ToString() method, is not the Name (well, ToString() is printing the name by default anyway).  You can try override ToString() method to print something else, you will see what I mean.

But of course you can define your own DataTemplate and binding to different property.

```
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding XXXXX}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```